# Why ADO VBA code returns only 6559 records?

Tags: vba, ado, adodb

I try to make macro that operate with sql statements with ADO liblary, but actually it returns only 6559 records, while one of my table have 72k records.
Why?

Recently, I've noticed, that actually my code does not returns 6559, but rows number - 65537. So when I decrease number of the rows in sheet to 72092, I even gets less rows (6550).

Another thing I noticed is that rs.RecordCount returns "-1".

Here is code for my subproccedure. It have three parameters: sql statement (sqlstmt), destination sheet name (sheet_name) and destination range (destination1).

```
'subprocedure that execute sql statements and save resault in given worksheet
    Public Sub sql_query(ByVal sqlstmt As String, ByVal sheet_name As String, ByVal destination1 As String)

        Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
        Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim connstring As String
        Dim qt As QueryTable
        Dim tw_path As String
        Dim is_name As Boolean
        Dim sh As Worksheet

        '''making sheet if it doesn't exist
        is_name = False
        For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If sh.Name = sheet_name Then is_name = True
        Next
        If is_name = False Then ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)).Name = sheet_name

        ''' connection
        tw_path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
        connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & tw_path & ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;Persist Security Info=False"

        Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
        conn.ConnectionString = connstring
        conn.Open

        '''executing statement
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        rs.Source = sqlstmt
        rs.ActiveConnection = conn
        rs.Open

        '''saving records
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet_name).Activate
        Set qt = Worksheets(sheet_name).QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range(destination1))
        qt.Refresh

        '''end
        If rs.State <> adStateClosed Then rs.Close
        conn.Close
        If Not rs Is Nothing Then Set rs = Nothing
        If Not conn Is Nothing Then Set conn = Nothing
        Set qt = Nothing

        End Sub
```

Thanks for help

Comment: It's been my experience that ADO won't always load a recordset fully unless forced. Try adding rs.MoveLast after rs.Open to force it to read all records.

Comment: Thanks, but actually it dooes not helps :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using excel 2003 or a prior version, in which case a worksheet has a maximum of 65,536 rows. I would've put this in a comment instead of an answer but I'm 1 rep short of being able to comment :(. Sorry

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Actually I am using excel 2007 and ADO 6.0 library and one of my sheets really have 72 k rows :)
However, probably it is imposible to use tables with more then 65536 rows, couse when I split this sheet on two smaller sheets and just use SQL UNION command it works correctly.